# Function into a different file using this

Tags: typescript, this

I have a class that receive other classes of a know interface and a main method like this:

```js
// BusinessLayer.ts

import getForm from "./getForm";
/*
 * other import statements
 */


class BusinessLayer {
  constructor(
    protected cacheLayer: ICacheLayer,
    protected databaseLayer: IRepositoryLayer,
    protect serviceLayer: IServiceLayer,
  ) {}

  async execute(arg1: number, arg2: string) {
    const { dependencies, formTree } = await getForm();

    ...
    ...
    ...

    return result;
  }
}
```

To keep it clean I split this function into smaller one, each one in a file, for example the `getForm()`

```js
// getForm.ts

import type BusinessLayer from "../BusinessLayer";

async function getForm(this: BusinessLayer) {
  const formFromCache = await this.cacheLayer.getFormFromCache();
  if (formFromCache) {
    return formFromCache;
  }

  const formFromDB = await this.databaseLayer.getFormFromDatabase();
  if (!formFromDB) {
    throw new Error("Form Not Found");
  }

  const formValue = formFromDB.value;

  return formValue;
}

export default getForm;
```

First I got a dependency cycle error, that was solved by the `import type` on getForm.ts but now I'm getting

**The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'BusinessLayer'.ts(2684)**

Comment: "I split this function into smaller one, each one in a file" the problem is that semantically `getForm` is not just a function. It is a method. This function makes no use outside of the class and even if you want to reuse it with another class you should better use composition or inheritance. So you are trying to overcome problems you have created yourself.

Comment: In fact the point of this approach is just to keep file short, not to reuse them. I have already tried to mix all this with genercis and notice it would be impossible heheh

Comment: Not sure about the amount of code you have in this file. But I would still consider a different approach. If your class is doing too much maybe extract something into separate class and use composition? In the end IDEs do have collapsing regions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from my comment. You need to call function with the context you want. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=65&pln=17&pc=5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIAcD2BnYMHKATwBk4TpkBvAKGUeQHMIwAxYgW3ahy4AicMHABGcPBABcyABQBKZAF4AfMgBuOYABM6AXzqhIsRClQBhRAAsIFKlFoMmrDt179LCGzIXK1mnX1DcGh4JDQAZWh1YCQ7aBoDOgQAGwk8ZAAhAFcCEAg8PHiHekYEHBA8MChshCIoWSdGLD5IOohtZARrW0poGQse4oAaJuQWnDbITu1hMQle%20wHMXAJ68j6oUaZx1oh2zskoGLjNgajj2MXobeRFRLonCRIQBGQIAA997MhZOChmABGGQgbJcUQ3ZD-ZgAJhkVSgoGY9zG5UqYFoyG02AgIGxr2ABWGyBg3AAKlAICg9MooQB3OCEFhsThQLgAOm6KRSsjAVmAeHkAG5HowDElnq8SdlXmBgBVma42bz%20XgZDk8gUipsUWUKlUSW4%20FxPDZaXAGUy%20QLOUNNuyXKyeMbTRAFCLGMAYHJSWz3CaerqmJSwNkoCBDX6XT0Pcgknr0ZHnfwBJlzZaMda8OzZiJxJJig6WUaU3N827hU4vXIAIS%205OCTJBxh8vh05D5dsAUSgfAaACIncgAHKTZCcGXafuVsWirr6jH1gBqcBS2RQSiT-tT7PUq-XIqcIbDEeX%204gIr0QA)

```
const { dependencies, formTree } = await getForm.call(this);
```

Comment: Tks man, this really did the job!! :)